# "Licences" module not found by xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd, xlutils

I've installed xlutils and am trying the following code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

input_file = open_workbook('DataTestFile.xlsx')

for s in input_file.sheets():
    print('Sheet:',s.name)
    for row in range(s.nrows):
        values = []
        for col in range(s.ncols):
            values.append(s.cell(row,col).value)
        print(','.join(values))
    print()
```

(as per tutorial book found [here](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python_excel_09/excel-lightning.pdf))

I'm getting an error indicating that the licences module is not found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\workspace_python\xxxxxxx\TestPack\test_file_excel.py", line 7, in <module>
    from xlrd import open_workbook
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import licences
ImportError: No module named 'licences'
```

However, I can confirm that the file licences.py is present in the same folder as file _ *init* _.py quoted above:

[image: files in my xlrd folder]

How come it's not recognized?